# How to make a library act as a no-op in Debug mode?

Tags: java, android, robolectric, flurry

This question pertains specifically to Flurry, but I'd be curious how to do it for any 3rd party language.

Essentially, Flurry is causing a crash in Robolectric (as per: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/144) and the only way I can get my unit tests to work is to remove all calls to Flurry (e.g. FlurryAgent.init, FlurryAgent.onStartSession, etc...).

Short of putting all of these under a BuildConfig.Debug 'if' block (which means having a lot of them), is there any way to globally cause all calls to FlurryAgent compile as no-ops in debug mode, for example?

LeakCanary is a good example of the effect I would like to see.

```
 dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
 }
```

Comment: You should disable Flurry reports for Debug builds. For example this can be done with a flag which is checked at compile time if flurry enabled or disabled.

Comment: @nenick Could you give some more detail in an answer for this question?

Comment: @nenick so my debug builds will not report Flurry events. How I would explain it to my QA? :) Sure you can create test flavour but it is bringing more complexity than necessary

Answer (score 2):

We are also using Flurry. So for the rest of application Flurry is hidden by our `Analytics` class and this helps us easy to mock it and verify interaction with it.

To test `Analytics` itself we use another technics:

```
public class Analytics {
   ...
   protected startFlurry(Context context, String apiKey) {
      FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, apiKey);
   }
   ...
}
```

And the test:

```
public class AnalyticsTest {
   ...
   @Before
   protected setUp() {
     analytics = new Analytics();
     analyticsSpy = spy(analytics);
     doNothing().when(analyticsSpy).startFlurry(any(Context.class), anyString());
   }
   ...
}
```

This is workaround but I don't have better solution for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping there was a way to do it without wrapping it up in another class, but maybe not - I must be too used to unit testing in Javascript, where you can basically do whatever you want.

Comment: Some library creators think about clients have to write unit tests. Some don't :) If you would use some language (Kotlin for exmaple) that supports class extensions then you might approach this problem differently.

Comment: @EugenMartynov how do you mock Analytics if it's a class extending Application who's calling it?

Comment: I don't get. Can you share code or create another question?